# Excel extraction from database using PEAR: column with enumeration

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel, pear

There is a a section of my website that allows to extract an Excel file using data from a database. In order to accomplish this task, I am using the PEAR library.

The Excel table that is generated consists of 32 columns. My current objective is to add a 33rd column that simply generates a number starting at 1 and increases every row (just in order to easily identify the different rows once printed). I understand this is probably somewhat of a simple task, but I am a beginner programmer and therefore am not familiar with some of the terminology. Therefore I am having trouble finding exactly what I am looking for.

Currently this is how I am populating the table with the data following my SQL Query, and everything is working great.

```
$worksheet->write($row, $column , $sqlquery[$i][$column], $format);
```

From my understanding, I should be able to accomplish my objective using a FOR loop similar to something like

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
  {
  echo  $i;
  }
```

However, I am already using the following two loops (one for the $row and one for the $column)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sqlquery); $i++) {

    $row= $i + 4;

    for ($j = 0; $j < 33; $j++) {
```

My lack of experience is lacking here and I am blocking as I do not know how to integrate the solution or perhaps I am using the wrong strategy all together.

Full examples are preferred, if possible, as they are easier for me to understand.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within your second loop, you already have `i` that is a counter. Just add 1 to make it human friendly ( start from 1 instead of 0 ) :

```
if ($i<33) {
    $worksheet->write($row, $column , $sqlquery[$i][$column], $format);
} else {
    $worksheet->write($row, $column , $i+1 , $format );
}
```

and of course, change your inner loop to $j < 34